# How can I copy a graphic drawn on a PictureBox to clipboard?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, graphics

I have a software that builds a 3D text by using `grafx.DrawString()` and I need to copy this graphic to clipboard. When I try to do so, it throws a NullReferenceException.

How can I copy the graphics drawn on a PictureBox?

This is the code to draw the text:

```
Dim grafx As Graphics
Private Sub draw_block_text10()
    Dim text_size As SizeF
    Dim back_brush As Brush = Brushes.Black 'COLOR FOR THE BOARDER TEXT
    Dim fore_brush As Brush = Brushes.Blue 'COLOR FOR THE MAIN TEXT


    Dim fnt As New Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", NumericUpDown1.Value, FontStyle.Regular)
    Dim location_x, location_y As Single 'USED IT FOR THE LOCATION
    Dim i As Integer

    'CREATE A GRAPHIC OBJECT IN THE PICTUREBOX.
    grafx = Me.PictureBox2.CreateGraphics()
    'CLEAR THE PICTUREBOX
    grafx.Clear(Color.White)

    'LOOK THE REQUIRED SIZE TO DRAW THE TEXT
    text_size = grafx.MeasureString(Me.TextBox1.Text, fnt)

    'ELIMINATE THE REDUNDANT CAlCULATION AFTER GETTING THE LOCATION.
    location_x = (Me.PictureBox2.Width - text_size.Width) / 2
    location_y = (Me.PictureBox2.Height - text_size.Height) / 2

    'FIRST, DRAW THE BLACK BACKGROUND TO GET THE EFFECT,
    'AND THE TEXT MUST BE DRAWN REAPETEDLY FROM THE OFFSET RIGHT, UP TO THE MAIN TEXT IS DRAWN.
    For i = CInt(nupDepth.Value) To 0 Step -1
        grafx.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, fnt, back_brush, _
        location_x - i, location_y + i)
    Next
    Dim mydataandtimeforsave = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    'DRAW THE ROYAL BLUE FOR THE MAIN TEXT OVER THE BLACk TEXT
    grafx.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, fnt, fore_brush, location_x, location_y)
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(Me.PictureBox2.Width, Me.PictureBox2.Height)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.Clear(Color.Transparent)

    ''Perform Drawing here

End Sub
```

This is the code to copy to clipboard:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject( _
    DirectCast(PictureBox2.Image.Clone, Bitmap), _
    True)
    Beep()
```

Comment: The code is splattering pixels on top of control, standard bug induced by CreateGraphics().  They won't last for very long, easiest to see by minimizing and restoring the window.  And sure, copying it to the Clipboard can't work.  Do this the correct way, use the picturebox' Paint event instead.  Now you can create the bitmap with its DrawToBitmap() method.  Or refactor the code into a separate method that takes a Graphics argument so you can call it both from the Paint event handler and the code that generates the clipboard image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Graphics` object created from a PictureBox control (`PictureBox.CreateGraphics()`) to draw on doesn't actually set/change the `Image` property of the PictureBox. You can confirm that by checking for `PictureBox2.Image Is Nothing`, which will return true *if the PictureBox had no image before drawing on it*.

Instead, create an `Image` with the dimensions of the PictureBox, use `Graphics.FromImage()` to create your `Graphics` object, draw what you need to draw, and then assign the image to the `PictureBox.Image` property.

Something like this should work fine:

```
Dim bmp As New Bitmap(PictureBox2.Width, PictureBox2.Height)
Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    g.Clear(Color.White)

    text_size = g.MeasureString(Me.TextBox1.Text, fnt)

    location_x = (Me.PictureBox2.Width - text_size.Width) / 2
    location_y = (Me.PictureBox2.Height - text_size.Height) / 2

    For i = CInt(nupDepth.Value) To 0 Step -1
        g.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, fnt, back_brush, location_x - i, location_y + i)
    Next

    g.DrawString(TextBox1.Text, fnt, fore_brush, location_x, location_y)
End Using

PictureBox2.Image = bmp
```

Note: Always remember to dispose the created Graphics object when you finish using it either by calling [`.Dispose()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.dispose) or by wrapping it in a [`Using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) like what I did above.

Comment: Tank you , you made my day , now i no how to properly set this. Its works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

Clipboard.SetDataObject(DirectCast(PictureBox2.Image.Clone, Bitmap), True)

Use

```
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(PictureBox2.Image, 2)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).